# JavaScript/jQuery call function every 5 minutes for an 8 hour period

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function every 5 minutes for an 8 hour period.  The catch is it must be the on the same day.  For example if the user logs onto the system at 11:59pm on 3/29 and it's now 12:01am on 3/30 the function should no longer be called.

I know how to call it ever 5 minutes and have the jQuery ajax call coded; that part is fine.  My problem is figuring out the date.

Here is the code:

```
var startDay;

function keepAlive(currDay) {
    var today = new Date().getDate();
    if (currDay == today) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ alive: 'true' }",
            url: "../ses/imsi_ses_edit.aspx/KeepSessionAlive",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    startDay = new Date().getDate();
    keepAlive(startDay); //Make sure the function fires as soon as the page is loaded

    setTimeout(keepAlive, 300000); //Then set it to run again after five minutes
}
```

Comment: I think this will be easier on the server side. On client side there are many catchs. Can you use a cron or something like that?

Comment: you seem to have a setTimeout() -- that only gets called once, but I assume you already know that.

Comment: Have you thought about things like different time-zones etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var initDate = new Date(); // Or get the user login date from an HTML element (i.e. hidden input)
var interval;

function keepAlive() {
    // Do stuff (ajax call)
}

window.onload = function() {
    keepAlive();

    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        if(now.getTime() - initDate.getTime() < 8*60*60*1000 && now.getDate() == initDate.getDate()) {
            keepAlive();
        }
        else {
            // Stop the interval
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 5*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Satoshi, I am going to try the code you provided.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: No problem, note that I slightly changed it in order to make the ajax call when the page loads (looking at your code seems like this is what you want)

Comment: Actually I just threw that code together in about 5 minutes.  I don't need it to run on page load, only every 5 minutes for a duration of 8 hours and only on the day that it started.  I think you're original code is what I needed.  I'm going to mark this as the answer.  It runs every 5 minutes perfectly, confirming the rest is going to be more of a challenge.  We have to do this as this site is used by iphone's out in the field on hospital wifi networks and they keep getting knocked off but we want them to have to login each day.  I appreciate your help.  I was confused how to handle the date.

Answer (score 2):

```
function keepAlive(currDay) {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ alive: 'true' }",
        url: "../ses/imsi_ses_edit.aspx/KeepSessionAlive",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
window.onload = function() {
    var startDay = new Date().getDate();
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var interval;
    keepAlive(startDay); //Make sure the function fires as soon as the page is loaded

    interval = setInterval( function () {
        if (startDay != new Date().getDate() || startTime < (new Date().getTime() - 1000*60*60*8)) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        keepAlive();
    }, 300000); //Then set it to run again after five minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you asked for but I believe my answer will be useful to many other users.
In my sample, setInterval repeats the action (of sending data to the server using AJAX) every 5 minutes.
Below it is setTimeout function which clears the interval after 8 hours, using the interval ID. Hope it helps someone.

```
repeatUpdateSession();
function repeatUpdateSession() {
    var updateSession = window.setInterval(function() {
        var myemail = $.trim($("#myemail").html());
        $.post('includes/updatesession.php', {myemail:myemail}, function(data){
            //alert(data);
        });
    }, 5*60*1000);
    setTimeout( function() {
        clearInterval(updateSession);
    }, 8*60*60*1000);
}
```